# Integrate $ \int \sinh 2x \cosh x dx$

Tags: integration, integration-by-parts

I want to integrate

$$\int \sinh 2x \cosh x dx$$

my steps was as follow:

$$
\int \sinh 2x \cosh x dx =
\\
\sinh 2x . \sinh x - 2 \int \cosh 2x \sinh x dx =
\\
\sinh 2x . \sinh x - 2 (\cosh 2x . \cosh x - 2 \int \sinh 2x \cosh x dx)
\\\equiv
-4  \int \sinh 2x \cosh x dx = \sinh 2x . \sinh x - 2 \cosh 2x . \cosh x
\\\equiv
\int \sinh 2x \cosh x dx = -\frac{1}{4}\sinh 2x . \sinh x + \frac{2}{4} \cosh 2x . \cosh x = \frac{\cosh^{3}}{2}
$$

But the result shown [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csinh%202x%20%5Ccosh%20x%20dx) is $2/3 \cosh^3(x)$.

Wat am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before the penultimate line, you have

$$\int \sinh 2x\cosh x\,dx = \sinh 2x \sinh x - 2\cosh 2x \cosh x + 4\int \sinh 2x\sinh x\,dx.$$

You forgot the one on the left to obtain a factor $-4$ in the penultimate line where it should have been $-3$. Nothing serious, ordinary lapse of attention.

Answer (score 4):

I always prefer to do a $u$-substitution rather than integration by parts. As an analogy to circular trig functions, $$\sin(2x) = 2\sin x \cos x$$ and it can be shown that $$\sinh(2x) = 2 \sinh x \cosh x$$ Using this identity, rewrite the integral to get:
$$\int \sinh(2x) \cosh(x) \, dx = \int 2 \sinh(x)\cosh(x)\cosh(x) \, dx \\
= 2 \int \sinh(x) \cosh^2(x) \, dx$$
Now is the time for a $u$-substitution where we let $u = \cosh(x)$, and then $du = \sinh(x) \, dx$. Thus,
$$2 \int \sinh(x) \cosh^2(x) \, dx = 2 \int u^2 \, du \\
= 2\left(\frac{u^3}{3} \right) + C$$
Back-substituting in the value of $u$ gives your final answer
$$\frac{2}{3} \cosh^3(x) + C$$